# Ordering a table by time and based on the first appearance of an ID

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm looking to order a log table so that it is grouped by id based on the first appearance of the id.  In my example below, I have a table 'test' and I want to group the table by id so that all the ids are together, i.e. list all '623' entries then all '444' entries.  I want the '623' entries to come first because the first '623' record came before the first '444' entries.

Input:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═════╗
║  uid  ║    time    ║ id  ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════╣
║  001  ║  01:45:10  ║ 623 ║
║  002  ║  02:45:20  ║ 444 ║
║  003  ║  03:45:30  ║ 444 ║
║  004  ║  04:45:40  ║ 623 ║
║  005  ║  05:45:50  ║ 623 ║
║  006  ║  06:45:00  ║ 444 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═════╝
```

Output:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═════╗
║  uid  ║    time    ║ id  ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═════╣
║  001  ║  01:45:10  ║ 623 ║
║  004  ║  04:45:40  ║ 623 ║
║  005  ║  05:45:50  ║ 623 ║
║  002  ║  02:45:20  ║ 444 ║
║  003  ║  03:45:30  ║ 444 ║
║  006  ║  06:45:00  ║ 444 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═════╝
```

The closest I've come is this:

```
select time, id from test group by id, time

    ╔═══════╦════════════╦═════╗
    ║  uid  ║    time    ║ id  ║
    ╠═══════╬════════════╬═════╣
    ║  002  ║  02:45:20  ║ 444 ║
    ║  003  ║  03:45:30  ║ 444 ║
    ║  006  ║  06:45:00  ║ 444 ║
    ║  001  ║  01:45:10  ║ 623 ║
    ║  004  ║  04:45:40  ║ 623 ║
    ║  005  ║  05:45:50  ║ 623 ║
    ╚═══════╩════════════╩═════╝
```

But this isn't exactly it because it's ordering by the id.  I'm not sure what the proper syntax is to have all the '623' entries get listed first because the first '623' record came before the first '444' entry.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Got the answer:**

```
SELECT test.time, test.id FROM
(
    (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM test ORDER BY time ASC) as distinct_test
    LEFT JOIN 
    test ON distinct_test.id = test.id
)
```

That makes sense now that I see it.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I just submitted an answer, then realized something. Your `id`s aren't distinct. Can you maybe adjust your example to include a distinct primary key, then a separate field to take the place of `id`? Or at least just rename `id` to something else?

Comment: The id values are meant to not be unique.  I added in a unique id field if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I know. What you did was exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you need to use; I tested it on your data and it worked. It's basically the same as Jason Swett's, except you must use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT t.id, t.time
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM `table`
      ORDER BY time ASC) distinct_t
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table` t ON distinct_t.id = t.id;
```

Comment: Thanks jeff.  I actually tried a LEFT JOIN for kicks and it did exactly what I wanted, but I'll still give you the answer.

Comment: If a regular left join worked, I think this answer and mine would effectively be the same thing, just written in a different order.

Comment: I actually tried your answer on the data, and it didn't produce the desired result. It was the right idea though, and I thank you for the code my answer was based off of.

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
      SELECT test.id,
             test.time
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id
                FROM test
            ORDER BY time ASC) distinct_test
  RIGHT JOIN test ON distinct_test.id = test.id
```

That might not work but it might at least put you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm?

```
SELECT time, id FROM test group by id, time order by id desc
```